# PS4 controller compatibility on Windows

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, compatibility, joystick, ps4

Is the Ps4 controller compatible with Windows 10? I bought a controller, but there is no response between the system and it. It connects normally via BT, but there is no feedback from the buttons. I've tried using DS4Windows, but without success either. Bought a BT adapter but nothing either. Someone give me a light

Comment: I can't quite remember what the app was called, but there is a third party app that allows the PS4 controller to be used on a Mac or PC. It's definitely out there. This was several years back for me though.,

Comment: What research have you done? It seems to me something like this would have a relatively well documented method if it is possible.